# Change error message in TIdTCPClient.Connect

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio

I'm using `TIdTCPClient`. It seems to be a simple thing to do, but I can't find a way to change the error message `"Already connected"` when I execute `tcpClient->Connect();`

So I set the `Host`, `Port`, and `ConnectTimeout`, and after all this I call the `Connect()`.

I tried to change that error message using `WriteLn()`, maybe is that the solution, but I could be using that in a wrong way.

I only want to show to the client (maybe in a `ShowMessage()` or in a `TLabel`), not necessarily to the server.

Comment: Please post the code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `TIdTCPClient::Connect()` if the client is already connected to a server (`TIdTCPClient::Connected()` returns `true`), you have to call `TIdTCPClient::Disconnect()` first.

If you are asking how to change the error message text itself, it is a localized string (`RSAlreadyConnected` in the `IdResourceStringsCore` unit), so just [localize your app](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internationalization_and_Localization) as needed.

Otherwise, you can simply use a `try..catch` to catch the `EIdAlreadyConnected` exception that is raised, and then display whatever text you want, however you want, eg:

```cpp
try {
  tcpClient->Connect();;
}
const (const EIdAlreadyConnected &) {
    ShowMessage("Already connected! Please disconnect first.");
}
catch (const Exception &) {
    ShowMessage("Error Connecting!");
}
```

Comment: Not working... I tried to use that in the way that you wrote, but no results, tried to get only the  **const** but no results, tried to override EIdAlreadyConnected, but it keeps showing the message "already connected". I just need to modify this message... Do you have another example?

Comment: No problem, i got this now, i did it with the return of the value of **Connected()**, but thanks for the help Remy!

Comment: You can't modify the text itself without altering Indy's source code, or localizing your app (or, catching the exception and altering its `Message` property). Are you seeing the error popup while running your app inside the debugger? If so, that is perfectly normal behavior, and you can configure the debugger to ignore `EIdAlreadyConnected` if needed. Otherwise, if you are seeing the error appear while running your app outside of the debugger, that would mean the compiler's exception handling is not working properly. That's a known issue on Android and OSX, for instance.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, I got it, but I had another idea: To disable an "enable" button if clicked and vice-versa to another one. I thank I did a little bit much, with that I could do what I needed. And thanks for the explanation, I didn't know about that.